# Left Join with where optional

Tags: oracle, join, left-join, where-clause

I've a two tables and a clause where, but I want to bring the left side always independent of the clause where.

Example

```
table a
-----------------
id
nome

table B
-----------------
id
nome
date
id_a
```

I've been a query and it works when don't exists value in table B or when the clause WHERE fetch.

```
select  ta.* from table_a ta
left join  table_b tb on ta.id =  tb.id_a
where 
tb.date = '2015-07-05' or tb.id is null
```

In my table has a registry with tb.date = '2015-07-05'.  This query works, but I trying the query with tb.date = '2015-07-04' the query fetch with left side in join, but don't bring the row that have table_b  '2015-07-05'.

**I want fetch left side in join independent of the clause where.**

Comment: `'2015-07-05'` is a string and NOT a `DATE`. Either use `TO_DATE` or **ANSI** DATE literal `DATE '2015-07-05'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  ta.* from table_a ta
left join  table_b tb on (ta.id =  tb.id_a and tb.date = '2015-07-05');
```

Also, '2015-07-05' is considered a string in Oracle. Always use to_date to compare date values.